# p:overlayPanel close event

Tags: primefaces, overlay

I'm facing a difficulty in setting the close event of the overlaypanel. here is my code :

```
<h:panelGrid columns="6"  cellpadding="15" style="margin:auto;">        
    <p:graphicImage id="item1" value="resources/icons/item1.png"   />       
    <p:graphicImage id="item2" value="resources/icons/item1.png"/>
    <p:graphicImage id="item3" value="resources/icons/item1.png" />
 </h:panelGrid>

<p:overlayPanel id="overlay1" for="item1" showEffect="blind" hideEffect="explode" 
                showEvent="mouseover" hideEvent="mouseout" dismissable="false" my="left top" > 
    <h:panelGrid columns="4" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5"
                    style="display:block;margin:auto;">
                    <p:graphicImage value="resources/icons/item1-1.png" />
                    <p:graphicImage value="resources/icons/item1-2.png" />
                    <p:graphicImage value="resources/icons/item1-3.png" />                  
    </h:panelGrid>
</p:overlayPanel>
```

What I'm getting : The overlay is closed when the mouse is out of the image that triggers it.

What I want : The overlay to be closed when the mouse is out of it ( the overlay I mean).

the Reason why I want this, is that I want to create sub-menu with icons inside the overlay.

Comment: Please read your last paragraph. It contains contradictory information. You state you want A, you state you get B and then you ask how to achieve B. Or do you mean different things with "Overlay" and overlay?

Comment: over 'it'? Still not clear... The overlay is opened hovering a button and closed when you move out of the button and you want it to be closed when the mouse is over the button???  And there is no button in your code. Make a [mcve] please.

Comment: So you want to close an overlay when the mouse is over it so you can create a submenu inside the overlay...??? But you want it to be closed.... so you'll never see the submenu... I still don't get it at all... Sorry, it might be me missing things...

Comment: My bad! I wanted to say "out of it" , I edited again! Thank you very much.. hope it is clear now

Comment: https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/menu/menu.xhtml has 'overlay' functionality...

Comment: not exactly what I wanted but thank you for your help.. I think I'll go for html/css

Comment: You can try a 'none' event and add a click event handler on the body that does a close. But sometimes html is better. No need to do everything in jsf...